# How do to copy an ntext field from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL Server 2012 database that contains `ntext` fields with data that I would like to export and send to an SQL Server 2008r2 database. I have tried generating data only scripts using ssms targetting SQL Server 2008r2 but the resulting scripts produce syntax errors (due to the content of the fields). I have tried casting it as xml but that also produces syntax errors.

The servers are not connected so I need something I can email.

Thanks,
Trevor

Comment: Have you tried CASTing it as NVARCHAR(MAX) ??

Comment: Have you tried the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard in SSMS? Right-click on your database and it's under Tasks > Export Data...

Comment: casting it produces syntax errors in the script. same with ssms.